# Android's Vibrations... does exists in all Android's devices?

Tags: android, device, vibration

I know that the vibration is produced by hardware and it would be exists or not in each Android-device depending of the OEM, but do you consider that the vibrations exists in all smarthphones that had Android?

Another question, how will do you check by code if the vibration exists in the device?

Thx in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

To use Vibrations you need to add this permission in the manifest.

```
android.permission.VIBRATE
```

Based on this the Android market would automatically exclude the devices that does not include it. However it is safe to assume that it would exist in all device and you need to do nothing extra in the code for checking it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just assume the ability for a phone to vibrate exists in all phones and not write any code to check for it.